# How do I make my private Ethereum network public?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, network

So after a lot of reading I was able to make my own private Ethereum network, most of the readings I did showed me how to test it privately, but none of them actually explained how to make it public, if I could get an explanation on how, or a link to a guide would be appreciated!

Comment: One difference between public and private blockchains is that no third parties are allowed to interact with a private network. To make it public you have publicize the details of your network, like genesis block, and how to interaction with other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Making public means to allow others to be able to connect to your chain.

So you need to provide details on how to add a new node to the chain. These details include:

- Genesis block: The genesis file which was used to create the chain
- bootnode: The enode url of any of your nodes which is running

Anyone having these details will be able to connect to your chain